# Why is Vue v-bind:class not updating?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Updating data property does not update dynamic class.

Have tried setting data property through computed value.

```
<div class="customize-box" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{active: customizeBoxVisible}"></div>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isSelected: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            customizeBoxVisible: {
                get() {
                    return this.isSelected;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.isSelected = value;
                }
            }
       },
       methods: {
            select() {
                this.isSelected = true;
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

Inspecting component data in chrome dev tools shows that customizeBoxVisible is set to true. After toggling isSelected in dev tools, class gets applied.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `v-bind:class="{ active: isSelected }"` work?

Comment: Yes, if I set the initial value to true or toggle it from false to true in vue dev tools, class gets applied as expected.

Comment: I've also tried changing v-bind:class to use an object:
`<div class="customize-box" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{active: object.isSelected}">`
, updated data to:   `data() {
            return {
                object: {isSelected: false}
            }
        },`
and then in select method:
`select() {
                this.$set(this.object, 'isSelected', true);
            }`

Comment: I've also tried committing isSelected to store through a mutation and then using a getter to return from computed property.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling select method but never changing isSelected data value. The correct way to toggle isSelected value is.

```
methods: {
    select() {
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see in methods select is setting this.isSelected to true.

Comment: But you are only setting it to true, and never setting it to false, so it will never toggle data value. Or even the first click is not setting the class?

Comment: The first click is not setting the class

Comment: I see, I thought your problem were isSelected toggling. The code you put in your question fully represents your component? If so, have your tried wrapping your div in a <template> tag? Vue components require this tag to be component root. Maybe it could be causing some random problems, but it should show an error anyway.

Comment: It is inside a <template> tag. What's weird is value is being updated in vue dev tools
[link]https://brandable.s3.amazonaws.com/code/Screen%20Shot%202019-05-31%20at%202.12.20%20PM.png
Then if I click on the checkmark in dev tools to set it to false, then back to true, class gets applied.

Comment: This is pretty weird, I copied and pasted your code and it seems to work as intended. If you start isSelected with true value, the class appears as default?

Comment: If start with true, class appears as expected.

Comment: Can you post your full component? It doesn't make sense to not update class as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was migrating from a jQuery to a Vue.js application and forgot to remove a click handler which removed the active class from my element. Everything works as expected.